# Script for running a batch file as Administrator without prompting for password

Tags: vbscript

The below script works on Windows XP as expected. The script abc.bat would run as Administrator without a prompt for password(password is supplied automatically). But the same script is not working on our Windows 7 Box. Are there any changes required? I have no experience with VB Scripting. Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Const USER               = "administrator"
Const PASS               = "*********"
Const WSNAME_COMMANDLINE = "C:\support\abc.bat"

Dim fso         : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim WSHShell    : Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim WshNetwork  : Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim oDic        : Set oDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim objArgs     : Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Dim oProcessEnv : Set oProcessEnv = WshShell.Environment("PROCESS")

Dim sPathToRunAs, iReturnCode

sPathToRunAs = oProcessEnv("SystemRoot")&"\System32\runas.exe"
''msgbox sPathtorunas

if Not fso.FileExists(sPathToRunAs) Then : WScript.Quit(1) 'Can't find RunAs

'''msgbox "runas /user:" & USER & " " & CHR(34) & WSNAME_COMMANDLINE & CHR(34)
iReturnCode=WshShell.Run("runas /user:" & USER & " " & CHR(34) & WSNAME_COMMANDLINE & CHR(34), 2, FALSE)

Wscript.Sleep 40                  ' Time for window to open.
WshShell.AppActivate(sPathToRunAs)' Activate the Window
Wscript.Sleep 3
WSHShell.SendKeys PASS & "~"      ' Send the password
Wscript.Sleep 3

''msgbox "done"
```

Comment: Have you tried the /savecred switch for runas? It should make it so that the password is only needed the first time. (http://superuser.com/questions/368771/opening-a-program-as-a-different-user-with-savecred-fail)

Comment: We do not want the users using the system to need to know the Admin credentials. So this option is ruled out for our business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the script on Windows 7 with UAC (User Account Control) disabled?

You can find a howto on disabling UAC here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off

If UAC is the reason for your issue, you may use windows task scheduler to avoid this like it is explained here: http://poundcomment.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/how-to-create-a-whitelist-uac-for-windows-7/

Comment: Yeah we did decide to disable it for now, and all is good so far. Thank you.